# Как получить URL изображения?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Безуспешно пробую получить src следующими способом:

```
Element element = document.select("div.imgTagWrapper").first();
imgUrl = element.attr("src");
```

или этим

```
Element element = document.getElementsByClass("imgTagWrapper").first();
imgUrl = element.tagName("src").text();
```

Из этого HTML

```
<div id="imgTagWrapperId" class="imgTagWrapper" style="height: 342.857px;">
    <img alt="Amanda Uprichard Women's Wren Maxi, Fluro Pink, S"
        src="https://images-na.ssl-images-    amazon.com/images/I/71jou38OlPL._UX342_.jpg"
        data-old-hires="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71jou38OlPL._UL1500_.jpg"
        class="a-dynamic-image  a-stretch-horizontal"
        id="landingImage" data-a-dynamic-image="{&quot;https://images-na.ssl-images-[740,569],&quot;https://images-na.ssl-images-[445,342],&quot;https://images-   na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71jou38OlPL._UX466_.jpg&quot;:[606,466]}"
        style="max-width: 264px; max-height: 342.857px;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала выбираете элементы с тегом `img`, затем считываете атрибут `src`:

```
Document page = Jsoup.parse(s);
Element imageElement = page.select("img").get(0);
String link = imageElement.attr("src");
```

где `s` – исходный HTML.